# PowerShell 3 not installed with .NET Framework 4.51

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, powershell

I want to upgrade to PowerShell 3 or 4 and have PowerShell 2 currently on my systems:

CLRVersion                     2.0.50727.5485
BuildVersion                   6.1.7601.17514
PSVersion                      2.0 
WSManStackVersion              2.0
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0}
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.1

I have two systems configured the same way. Currently my systems have 4.5.1 versions of the .NET Framework, Multi-Targeting Pack (and ENU) and SDK. They also have .NET Framework SDK and Framework Multi-Targeting Pack in .NET 4.5 too. I'm using VS2013, Update 4 with PowerShell Tools 1.3.

Because it has 4.5.1 and PS 2, I think this might have been the case when the systems were built:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2013/10/29/wmf-4-0-known-issue-partial-installation-without-net-framework-4-5.aspx

The suggested solution is:

Solution: Install .NET Framework 4.5, and then run the WMF 4.0 installer again.

Because the installed version is newer, I couldn't just install 4.5 from here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30653. I've removed just the 4.5.1 parts initially and tried to install - which didn't work. I then also removed the 4.5 components and attempted to install 4.5 again. When I remove the software, I'm getting warned while I do it that it can affect one or more running programs.

After removing 4.51 and 4.5 and starting the install, I get ".NET Framework 4.5 has not been installed because: The Windows Installer Service could not be accessed. This can occur if the Windows Installer is not correctly installed."

I've System Restored back to my initial state several times but any suggestions of how to do this so it works or get PowerShell 3 a different way would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

`Powershell` is **not** part of `.net framework`. It **depends** on it.
So, first install Latest .Net framework (seems like you do want 4.5 or 4.5.1)

And then download and install the appropriate version of `powershell`.

Detailed instructions can be found at following link - [Installing Windows PowerShell](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847837.aspx)

---

**Parts from that post -**

"Installing Windows PowerShell on Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2

These instructions explain how to install Windows PowerShell 3.0 on computers running Windows 7 with Service Pack 1 and Windows Server 2008 R2 with Service Pack 1. There are separate installation instructions below for computers running with the Server Core installation option of Windows Server 2008 R2.

Getting ready to install

•Before installing Windows Management Framework 3.0, uninstall any previous versions of Windows Management Framework 3.0.

To install Windows PowerShell 3.0

1.Install the full installation of Microsoft .NET Framework 4.0 (dotNetFx40_Full_setup.exe) from the Microsoft Download Center at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=212547.

Or, install Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 (dotNetFx45_Full_setup.exe) from the Microsoft Download Center at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=242919.

2.Install Windows Management Framework 3.0 from the Microsoft Download Center at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=240290.

For information about starting Windows PowerShell 3.0, see [Starting Windows PowerShell on Earlier Versions of Windows."](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847820.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to install PowerShell 4 is to use chocolatey for the installation. First install chocolatey by going to http://chocolatey.org and follow the install instructions (copy/paste the command they give and it will download and install automatically).

Then install PowerShell 4 by typing the command:

```
choco install PowerShell
```

and it will install PowerShell 4 and all dependencies for your system.

On systems that don't support PowerShell 4 this will install PowerShell 3 instead.

Comment: This worked. Thanks a lot. I'm not sure why but the answer from Vikas above, step 1, is what I said wasn't working. My installed version of .Net Framework was newer and attempting to remove and reinstall the .Net Framework then confused or corrupted the Windows Installer. Chocolatey got it done. Thanks again!